# How do you introduce singing in a text bubble in comics?

Tags: comics

How do you introduce singing in a text bubble in comics? Is there a singing text bubble, or is there some other way to show that a character is singing? Do you have a few examples showing how this is done in a comics panel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple way is to show some music notes in the dialogue that's sung.

[image]